# Dynamically generate html pages based off array JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have a PhoneGap Android app built with JQuery Mobile 1.4.2. It is an RSS feed reader. I populate the RSS feed with an Ajax call and display the information by iterating through the Array of events in the `#mainPage`. When the user clicks on the list item, they are redirected to a new page which has the full description of the event called `#eventPage`.

I would like to implement a swipe to next event feature once the user is viewing the `#eventPage`. Currently, I have the app set up to update the content of the current page on swipe, but I really like the fluid design of a new page coming into view on swipe.

Is there a method to generate new pages within the html framework based off the length of the array? Or is there a different method for achieving the above? Thanks for any input and I will do my best to explain if needed.

Some examples of this feature are found in the Wall Street Journal app and the Feedley app.

Answer (score 0):

use $.get(HTML_PAGE_URL) method to get the html content and set content to a div using .html(CONTENT) which is set to fluid. For example try something like below.

```
$.get( "test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: I understand how to transfer the data into a div from the example, but how does this create a new page for the next set of information to display?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code below :

`.hide { display: none; }`

```js
var _text = "your html";
var old_panel = $("#yourpanelid");
var new_panel = $('<div class="hide"></div>');

new_panel.html(_text);
old_panel.addClass('hide');
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of this?